# Update database from onClick using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, function

I am trying to update a database from an onClick procedure inside an anchor.

```
<a name=“fs1” onClick="updateArea1();"></a>
```

I am struggling with the function for **updateArea1** as I'm not really sure how I can pass the name **"fs1"** from the anchor and update the database from a script process.

I would essentially like the database to be updated like this: 
**UPDATE row WHERE id = 1 WITH (name_from_anchor)**

However... the variable does not HAVE to come from the name tag. It could be referenced in the parenthesis of the function like this if it's easier.

```
<a onClick="updateArea1(fs1);"></a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-- UPDATED --

**LAUNCH.PHP**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <script src="includes/scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function updateArea1(el) {
         $.post("includes/db_update.php", $("#console").serialize());
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <a name="fs1" onClick="updateArea1(this.name);"></a>
    <a name="fs2" onClick="updateArea1(this.name);"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

**DB_UPDATE.PHP**

```
<?php

include 'db_connect.php';   

$area1= mysqli_escape_String($con,$_POST[]);

$query = "UPDATE previewState SET selected='".$area1."' WHERE id='1';";

mysqli_query($con,$query);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: show your updateArea1() code

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where are you struggling?

Comment: Using names to refer elements is deprecated. Use ids

Comment: @aliasm2k since when is that deprecated?

Comment: Since when id's got introduced

Comment: By the way, your curly quotes will throw an error. Change `“fs1”` to `"fs1"` and make sure you don't still use those when choosing an answer from below.

Comment: IDs have always been around as have names. Can you show where you found this information as I am very curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `this` as argument can do:

```
<a name="fs1" onClick="updateArea1(this);"></a>

updateArea1(el){
  alert( el.name)
}
```

Comment: thanks @putvande - Can you also please tell me how I would complete the function to update the db? Basically the part that does this (UPDATE row WHERE id = 1 WITH name)

Comment: you would need to send name to server with ajax

Comment: thanks @charlietfl - I updated my code above. I am referencing another PHP file to update the DB but I'm not sure I'm going about it correctly.

Comment: no...you have no form to serialize, want to do something like:`$.post(url,{name: el.name})` then receive in php `$_POST['name']`

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged this question with Jquery, why dont you use a click handler for that element like,

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  updateAreat1($(this).attr('name'));
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple. [**Here's the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HKT6P/1/)

```
 <a name="temp"       onClick="updateArea1(this.name);">label</a>


 function updateArea1(el){
   alert( el)
 }
```

Comment: thanks @srvikram13 - Can you also tell me how I would complete the function to update the db? Basically the part that does this (UPDATE row WHERE id = 1 WITH name)

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a function to onclick event, you can access the element that triggered the event using this (If the function is global or in window scope).

So just use `this.name` within updateArea1 function.

```
function updateAreaa1(){
  updateDb(this.name);  //this will refer to the element that triggered the click event.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain _If the function is global or in window scope_?